# Manual triggering of events c#

Tags: c#, events, mouseevent

I have a button that when clicked displays some information, can i manually trigger the button clicked event in code ?

I need this so that when i click on some other button it automatically triggers this event too.

Comment: Why don't you just call the other eventhandler instead of triggering the event itself? Or subscribe the same eventhandler to both events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good way would be to have NO code (except a method/function call) in an event handler. this would made it possible to call it from any place in your program.

Comment: Also, take a look at patterns like MVC oder MVP. They will help you realizing this.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the sender or EventArgs, you could also simply use

```
Button1_Click(null, new EventArgs());
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the code replying to the button click in a function and call that function both in the event handler and in the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("button1");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("button2");
    button1_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Button.PerformClick()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do this,

1# -= Move the code which you have written in the button click event to another function and call this function in this button click event and in other button click event also.

2# - For the second button click event specify the first button click event as the event handler.

3# - call button1's event handler inside button2.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1_Click(sender, e);
}
```

I will advise you to go for the the second one, if you have to the same set of functionalities for both the buttons.

Comment: the problem there is I am making async calls to a few functions and this event i want triggered should happen at the end of it so i can specify the event handler for the second button to first button.